# change background image for the main window in Titanium-iphone

Tags: titanium

I have the following in Titanium:

```
var imageArray = [];
    imageArray[0] = 'photo0.png';
    imageArray[1] = 'photo1.png';
    ....
    imageArray[N] = 'photoN.png';


var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
    title:'Tab 1',
    backgroundImage:imageArray[0],
    backgroundColor:'#fff'
});
```

`win1` is my main window and when I click a button I want to change it's `backgroundImage` without need for recreating the window. Anyone any idea of how could I do that?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried using the `Ti.UI.currentWindow.setBackgroundImage()` function? I think you can use that but I don't think that the `Ti.UI.window` supports a background image array.

Comment: I tried this   Ti.UI.currentWindow.setbackgroundImage('photo1.png'); but nothing happens...no change!

Comment: where is your button code? Is the path correct or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can just set the backgroundImage of your window, like this:

```
win1.backgroundImage = "photo1.png";
```

It will works to you. But make sure that the image is in the Resources folder.

You have to use `Ti.UI.currentWindow` just when you are using external windows (with URL parameter in the window, using another JS file).

In the same context, the `Ti.UI.currentWindow` not works.